# how to submit a form through ajax only if the validation function retun true

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form in my page. onsubmit i have a function for validation. i need to send the values of form through ajax only if the validation function return true.
But my data is being submitted even if the validation return false. please help me out.
here is my code

form

```
<form id="form" method="post" onsubmit="return val()">
 <input type="text" name="name" id="t1" placeholder="name" class="i">
 <span id="msg1"></span><br>
 <input type="number" name="roll" id="t2" placeholder="roll no" min="0" class="i">
 <span id="msg2"></span><br>
 <input type="number" name="age" id="t3" placeholder="age" min="0" class="i">
 <span id="msg3"></span><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">                                  
</form>
```

The val function

```
function val()
    {
        var status=true;
        var name=$("#t1").val();
        var age=$("#t2").val();
        var roll=$("#t3").val();
        if(name=="")
        {
            $("#msg1").text("*name cannot be empty");
            status=false;

        }
        if(roll=="")
        {
            $("#msg2").text("*roll number cannot be empty");
            status=false;
        }
        if(age=="")
        {
            $("#msg3").text("*age cannot be empty");
            status=false;
        }
    return status;

    }
```

the function that i need to work only if the val() return true

```
$("form").submit(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>"+"att_controller/add_stud",
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            success: function(){
                if(confirm("added")){
                   $(".i").val(""); 
                }

            }

        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of inline submit handler and use the `val()` method in the unobtrusive event handler.

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (val()) {
        $.ajax(....)
    }
});
```